# Construction of an isomorphism between certain subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $S_4.$

Tags: finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Consider the following matrices $A:=$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} ,\ B: =\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ of multiplicative group $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $\sigma = (1234), \rho = (24) \in S_4.$ Let $G_1 = \left \langle {A,B}\right \rangle$ and $G_2= \left \langle {\sigma,\rho}\right \rangle.$ Is $G_1 \cong G_2?$

Here is my proof. But I have trouble showing $G_1 \cong G_2.$ Could someone advise please? Thank you.

Proof:

By direct computation, $o(A)=4$ and $o(B)=2.$ Since $A^i \neq B \ (i=0,1,2,3),$ $G_1 = \{A^{i}B^{j}| i=0,1,2,3 \wedge j=0,1\},$ whence $|G_1|=8.$

$\sigma^2=(13)(24), \ \sigma^3=(1432), \ \sigma^4= (1).$ So $o(\sigma)=4.$
Similarly, $o(\rho)=2.$ By similar reasoning above, $G_2= \{\sigma^i\rho^j| i =0,1,2,3 \wedge j=0,1\},$ whence $|G_2|=8.$

Given $A^iB^j \in G_1, $ let $A^iB^j \mapsto \sigma^i\rho^j.$ Clearly, this mapping is surjective. But how do I show this mapping is injective homomorphism?

Comment: You have not shown that all elements in the group generated by $A$ and $B$ can be written in the form you give. What about for example $BA$?

Comment: Thanks for correction. $BAB= A^3.$  Hence, $BA=A^3B^{-1}=A^3B , \ BA^2=A^3B^{-1}A=A^6B=A^2B, \ BA^3= A^2BA=A^5B=AB$

Comment: Also, $\rho\sigma\rho= \sigma^{-1}=\sigma^3.$ 

Hence, $\rho\sigma=\sigma^3\rho^{-1} = \sigma^3\rho, \ \rho\sigma^2 = \sigma^3\sigma^{-1}\rho= \sigma^2\rho, \ \ \rho\sigma^3=\sigma^2\rho\sigma=\sigma^5\rho=\sigma\rho. $